# ExtJS 4.2 Month Days (columns) for Holiday Planner

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have a requirement for a 4.2.1 ExtJS app that Im building, to have a `grid` like the image below:

[image]

The objective of the grid is to manage Holidays for employees.

I was thinking in setting the `columns` of the `grid dinamically`, but will need to fill the background `cell` depending of the type of "leave type", and also disable some `cells` depending on the days that are not supposed to work (like weekends, etc).

Any advice on how can I approach to the solution? Appreciate in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a commercial scheduler that does exactly that and more. See http://bryntum.com

Comment: Saki, is it possible to build that functionality? because I browse their examples and I didnt find anything like this. Appreciate it

Comment: I have personally configured their scheduler for holiday management. Of course, you can do it yourself with a grid. It is alway matter of what's more expensive: to spend time on that or buy a ready product. The author of the scheduler is very responsive, ask him on technical aspects.

Comment: Appreciate it!! Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just did the grid that I need :), here now is a post on how can I get fired the renderer on my dynamic columns. Appreciate it